# What is the flight plan to get Gaia in orbit around the Sun–Earth $L_2$ Lagrangian point?

Tags: orbit, orbital-maneuver, lagrangian-points, esa, gaia

[Gaia](http://sci.esa.int/gaia/) is a planned European Space Agency's (ESA) space observatory that will aim to chart a three-dimensional map of our Galaxy, the Milky Way. It is planned to operate around the Sun–Earth $L_2$ (SEL2) [Lagrangian point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point). What is the flight plan to get Gaia in orbit around SEL2? We can break this down into a few sub-questions:

- How many Earth flybys are planned?
- Will the Moon be used as gravity assist?
- Does it need lots of fuel to slow down near L2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Spaceflight Now](http://www.spaceflight101.com/gaia-mission-and-orbit-design.html) has a detailed overview of Gaia's launch sequence. There don't seem to be any Earth flybys or gravity assists planned. Just a single orbit around Earth after launch, then the burn to inject Gaia into its L2 transfer trajectory.
[image: Gaia launch sequence]
When it arrives at L2, a delta-V of 180 meters per second inserts Gaia into its orbit around L2.
Note that seems to disagree with [ESA's Gaia website](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Operations/Gaia), which states that Gaia will spend 4 days in Earth orbit for systems checks before the L2 injection burn.

Answer (score 1):

Arianespace’s sixth Soyuz launch from the Guiana Space
Center will carry the Gaia space telescope into orbit on L2 next 19th of December at 09:12:18 UTC. 
More detail about the launch sequence can be read from ESA site

http://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/news_20131206

and arianespace launch kit:

http://www.arianespace.com/images/launch-kits/launch-kit-pdf-eng/VS06-launchkit-GB2.pdf

Day - 4

E.